# Pandas - Pivot/stack/unstack/melt

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| name | value 1 | value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 101 |
| A | 100 | 102 |
| A | 100 | 103 |
| B | 200 | 201 |
| B | 200 | 202 |
| B | 200 | 203 |
| C | 300 | 301 |
| C | 300 | 302 |
| C | 300 | 303 |

And I'm trying to get to this:

| name | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 4 | value 5 | value 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 101 | 100 | 102 | 100 | 103 |
| B | 200 | 201 | 200 | 202 | 200 | 203 |
| C | 300 | 301 | 300 | 302 | 300 | 303 |

Here is what i have tried so far;
`dataframe.stack()`
`dataframe.unstack()`
`dataframe.melt(id_vars=['name'])`

I need to transpose the data by ensuring that;

1. The first row remains as it is but every subsequent value associated with the same name should be transposed to a coulmn.
2. Whereas the second value B (for. ex) should transpose it's associated value as a new value under the column A values, it should not form a separate altogether.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```py
def fn(x):
    vals = x.values.ravel()
    return pd.DataFrame(
        [vals],
        columns=[f"value {i}" for i in range(1, vals.shape[0] + 1)],
    )


out = (
    df.set_index("name")
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(fn)
    .reset_index()
    .drop(columns="level_1")
)
print(out.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | name | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 4 | value 5 | value 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 100 | 101 | 100 | 102 | 100 | 103 |
| 1 | B | 200 | 201 | 200 | 202 | 200 | 203 |
| 2 | C | 300 | 301 | 300 | 302 | 300 | 303 |

Answer (score 3):

### Flatten values for each name

```py
(
    df.set_index('name')
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.flat))
    .rename(columns=lambda x: f'value {x + 1}')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option using `melt,` groupby`, and [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) (from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/)):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.melt('name', ignore_index = False)
.sort_index()
.drop(columns='variable')
.assign(header = lambda df: df.groupby('name').cumcount() + 1)
.pivot_wider('name', 'header', names_sep = ' ')
)
  name  value 1  value 2  value 3  value 4  value 5  value 6
0    A      100      101      100      102      100      103
1    B      200      201      200      202      200      203
2    C      300      301      300      302      300      303
```